# Repeat a specific code line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian-based

I have writed a simple bash script,with dialog, that I use for post-installation on deepin distro. The script have a simple menu created with dialog, now my problem is that I don't know how to repeat the menu after every command is completed.

This is part of the script:

```
sudo apt-get install dialog
 cmd=(dialog --separate-output --checklist "Seleziona i programmi che vuoi installare:" 22 76 16)
 options=(1 "Impostazione Mirror GARR" off # qualsiasi impostazione può essere impostata su "on"
 2 "Aggiornamento di sistema" off
 3 "Installazione font Microsoft" off
 4 "Installazione Gdebi" off
 5 "Synaptic" off
 6 "BleachBit" off
 7 "Open JDK 8" off
 8 "Supporto lettura DVD" off
 9 "LibreOffice" off
 10 "VLC Media Player" off
 11 "Flash Player" off
 12 "Google Chrome" off
 13 "Teamiewer" off
 14 "Skype" off
 15 "Brasero" off
 16 "iFuse per supporto device Apple" off
 17 "Kodi" off
 18 "Gimp" off
 19 "Telegram" off 
 20 "Enpass Password manager" off
 21 "Opera Browser" off
 22 "GUFW" off
 23 "Vivaldi Browser" off
 24 "Risparmio energetico TLP" off
 25 "Pulizia del sistema" off)
 choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
 clear
 for choice in $choices
 do
 case $choice in

 1)
 #Setting mirror on italian server GARR
  echo "Impostazione Mirror GARR"
 cd $HOME &
cp /etc/apt/sources.list backup.sources.list
bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list
# Generated by deepin-installer
# deb [by-hash=force] http://packages.deepin.com/deepin unstable main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://packages.deepin.com/deepin unstable main contrib non-free
##########################################################################################
deb [by-hash=force] http://ba.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/deepin/ panda main contrib non-free
EOF'
      sudo apt-get update
 ;;

2)
 #Update of the repo and upgrade the system
clear
  echo "Aggiornamento del sistema"
apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
 ;;
```

Comment: Add an option `26 Exit` and use a while loop covering the whole script.

Comment: Yes, but as is now after a command is executed, the bash script exit. It's possible to use the while command for every single command of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple test seems to work fine. Give it a try:

```
$ cmd=(dialog --separate-output --checklist "Seleziona i programmi che vuoi installare:" 22 76 16)
$ options=(1 "Impostazione Mirror GARR" off 2 "Aggiornamento di sistema" off 3 "Installazione font Microsoft" off 4 "Exit" off)
$ while [ "$choices" -ne "4" ];do choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty);case $choices in 1) echo "number one" && sleep 5;;esac;done
```

Comment: I think it needs to be `while [[ "$choices" -ne "4" ]]` to avoid `-bash: [: : integer expression expected`, but good answer +